# View not showing up in relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a bracket `[` in a RelativeLayout. The top and bottom lines show. But the left line does not show. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
   <View
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have these two in the same position

```
 <View
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

Comment: Maybe there is something else going on in my code. I make the changes. I see the bar in the Graphical Layout, but when I run the device: nothing. Actually, even without the changes, the image was always visible in the Graphic Layout of eclipse. +1

Answer (score 1):

Both left and bottom has same statement

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Where do you want to place `left`?

If you want to kepp it in between top and bottom then

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/top"
```

Comment: Maybe there is something else going on in my code. I make the changes. I see the bar in the Graphical Layout, but when I run the device: nothing. Actually, even without the changes, the image was always visible in the Graphic Layout of eclipse. +1